# Add css class during scrolling up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Anyone know how I can add a class to an element during scrolling down and then a different class during scrolling up ?

The idea is to give a fixed element an elastic type feel so when the user is scrolling down the element will shift up slightly and vice versa.

Thanks,

Scott.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether they are scrolling down or up by checking the window's scroll top and comparing it to the previous scroll top using the [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll). [debounce it for efficiency reasons](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

```
(function($, window){
    var $window = $(window);
    var position = $window.scrollTop();
    var timeout;

    var debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };

    var checkPosition = function () {
        if(timeout !== null){
            //this will cancel the timeout if this function is called within 200ms
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }

        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > position) {
            //scrolling down
        } else {
            //scrolling up
        }

        position = scrollTop;

        //this function will fire if the user stops scrolling for 200ms
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            //user stopped scrolling
        }, 200);
    };

    var debouncedScroll = debounce(checkPosition, 50);

    $window.on('scroll', debouncedScroll);
})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: Ok great, thanks. Basically i want to add a class called 'scrolling' to an element during the scroll and when they stop scrolling i want the class to be removed. Would this be suitable for that ?

Comment: Updated answer to use a timeout, basically it will cancel the timeout when the scroll function is hit and then set a new one. This way if the scroll function isn't hit for 200 ms (aka the user isn't scrolling anymore) the function will fire

Comment: Have you tried lowering the 200ms? It could probably go a lot lower before it causes issues. Although keep in mind the debounce time of 50ms, it has to be higher than the debounce time since that is how often the function can be called at max. That can probably go down to 25 or so as well if you need even more instant reactions

Comment: It doesnt seem to change until the scrolling stops. Maybe the effect im after just isnt possible. Thanks for your help though.